# Переполнение стека при рекурсии c#

Tags: c#, рекурсия, графы

Всем привет! Пишу метод, которые будет проходится по графу depth-first методом. Вот мой код:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> DepthTraversalTree<T>(ITreeNode<T> root)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            if ((int)Convert.ChangeType(root.Data, typeof(int)) == 99999)
                return list;
            list.Add(root.Data);
            if (!(root.Children == null))
                foreach (var item in root.Children)
                {
                    list.Add(item.Data);
                    if (!(item.Children == null))
                    {
                        var s = DepthTraversalTree(item);
                        for (int i = 1; i < s.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            list.Add(s.ToArray()[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            return list;
        }
```

Не большие графы проходит без проблем. Но когда я отправляю граф на 100000 записей в глубину, выбрасывает Stackoverflow исключение. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Comment: Какую конкретно помощь? Ваш код упадет при первом же цикле в графе. Ну и у вас много мест для улучгений производительности.

Comment: Как его модернизировать, что б он не схлопывался при большем графе?

Comment: дело не в большом графе, а в том, что вы не учитываете вершины, по которым уже прошли, и прозодите по ним снова и снова и снова, пока ваш стек не закончится. А вообще 100 000 элементов в графе для современного ПК это сущие копейки.

Comment: Быть может это можно реализовать через цикл? Если да, подкиньте идею, пожалуйста)

Comment: Без рккурсии? Без рекурсии поиск в глубину работает через стек. Примеров реализаций полно в интернете, так как поиск в глубину это стандарный алгоритм, который изучают все, кто интересуется Computer Science. Я уверен, если вы просто погуглите "DFS Stack", вы найдете тьму примеров кода.

Comment: Да, обычно рекурсия не нужна - просто вместо рекурсивного вызова кладёте элемент, с которым надо вызвать функцию, в очередь, а очередь обрабатываете, причём можно в несколько потоков эту очередь обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стек - штука небольшая, не нужно засовывать в него такую кучу списков. Со стеком надо бережно.

Список у вас сквозной, так что можно использовать его по ссылке, а создать один раз.

```csharp
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthTraversalTree<T>(ITreeNode<T> root)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T> { root.Data };
    if (root.Children?.Count > 0)
    {
        DepthTraversalTree(root, list);
    }
    return list;
}

private static void DepthTraversalTree<T>(ITreeNode<T> node, List<T> list)
{
    if ((int)Convert.ChangeType(node.Data, typeof(int)) == 99999)
        return;

    foreach (var item in node.Children)
    {
        list.Add(item.Data);
        if (item.Children?.Count > 0)
        {
            DepthTraversalTree(item, list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: изменяемые коллекции - не круто

Comment: @Grundy ничего не понял, зачем здесь immutable?

Comment: ну вы возвращаете `IEnumerable<T>`, вам вообще необязательно какую либо коллекцию создавать.

Comment: @tym32167 догадываюсь, о чем вы, но я так не умею. Я вообще с реактивным программированием и fluent-интерфейсами не дружу, и Linq знаю только на уровне `.Where(x => x.Text == "Hello World!")`. А Linq+рекурсия - это вообще как? Я просто попытался помочь человеку, если мой код можно улучшить, я буду только рад, если кто-нибудь улучшит ответ. Если же я понаписал чушь и "так нельзя", я могу ответ удалить, мне не сложно, только скажите мне об этом, ну или минус поставьте. :)

Comment: ну код выглядит получше, чем у автора, но мне кажется у него циклы в графе, вот он и валится.

Comment: @tym32167 кстати, для гигантского дерева я бы просто создал обратные ссылки у элементов данных на родительскую ноду, и можно было бы гулять по дереву в обычном цикле без рекурсии в принципе. При этом размер дерева вообще не имел бы значения. Хоть триллион нод, любой глубины. Ну либо добавление последней ноды, которая сама по себе является ссылкой на родителя. Способов избежать рекурсии принципе - огромная куча. Да и псевдо-рекурсии с очередями тоже можно избежать, сведя потребление памяти на поиск к ~нулю. Кстати, в `HtmlAgilityPack` так реализована DOM.

Comment: обратные ссылки абсолтно не обязательны для итеративного прохода. Как я уже отметил сверху в комментах, можно гулять по графу и итеративно, используя стек для DFS и очередь для BFS

Comment: @tym32167 при наличии обратных ссылок, ни стек, ни очередь не нужны, меняется только приоритет навигации. Рекурсия тоже использует обычный стек.

Comment: не, рекурсия использует стек вызовов, который ограничен во вложенности. Обычный `Stack<>` ограничен только размером доступной памяти.

Comment: @tym32167 на низком уровне стек вызовов ограничен размером доступной памяти, выделенной под стек. Вложенность здесь не при чем, каждый последующий вызов может занимать разное количество памяти в стеке, в зависимости от дальности прыжка и передаваемых/возвращаемых аргументов. Поэтому убить стек можно и сотней вызовов, если постараться. А так алгоритмически разницы в том, какой стек использовать, нет, кмк.

Comment: алгоритмически и в памяти разницу надо считать в каждом случае отдельно, как мне кажется. Вызов функции реурсивно тратит процессор на сохранение и извлечение контекста функции и тратит память на хранение контекста. Потому, если итеративный вариант не предусматривает контекста (например, пройтись по связанному списку с начала и до конца), то итеративный вариант съест меньше памяти, если конечно рекурсия не будет развернута компиятором в итерации.